# Floating point division with bc in a single command

Tags: shell, bc

I am trying to convert bytes to TB from a certain match in a command / file.

The command I have got is:

```
var=$(($(cat test.txt | awk '/miscellaneous/ {print $NF}' | sed s/.$//)/1000**4)) ; printf $var
```

The value is supposed to be `6.182` but it prints only `6`. I just cannot figure out how to use `bc` in this command to get the floating values.

test.txt looks something like this:

```
  "a": 90919780478976,
  "b": 150812851408896,
  "c": 86337338950671,
  "miscellaneous": 6182842641393,
  "d": 0,
  "e": 58292669816832
```

Comment: Post the contents of `test.txt`

Comment: What do the contents of `test.txt` look like?

Comment: Edited my post with the content

Comment: Okay I did a little search and I could do this:
echo "scale=1;$(cat test.txt | awk '/miscellaneous/ {print $NF}' | sed s/.$//)/1000.0" | bc

But 1000**4 will not work since scale is only for division it seems

Comment: Crappy way of doing it seems to be:
echo "scale=3;$(cat test.txt | awk '/miscellaneous/ {print $NF}' | sed s/.$//)/1000.0/1000.0/1000.0/1000.0" | bc

Comment: Nvm, got this. export TB=$((1000**4));echo "scale=3;$(cat test.txt | awk '/miscellaneous/ {print $NF}' | sed s/.$//)/$TB" | bc

Comment: Is bc the only way or do we have a workaround when we do not have bc

Comment: Nvm, got this working with perl. export TB=$((1000**4));export NUM=$(cat test.txt | awk '/miscellaneous/ {print $NF}' | sed s/.$//); perl -e  '$A=$ENV{NUM}/$ENV{TB};$B=sprintf("%.4f",$A);print " $B TB \n"'

Comment: Another way.  export TB=$((1000**4));python -c "print $(cat test.txt | awk '/miscellaneous/ {print $NF}' | sed 's/,/.0/g') / $TB"

Answer (score 1):

`bc` is the wrong tool - try `awk`:

```
awk '/miscellaneous/ { print $2 / 1.0e12; }' < test.txt
```

6.18284

In your original example, it is doing division in `bash` which only understands integer arithmetic.